# What's the best way to store workout information?

Tags: data-structures

I'm playing around with a workout app (android), and want to match workouts to dates. The basic structure is :

1. Each date has zero or one workouts.
2. Each workout has one or more exercises.
3. Each exercise has a name, and one or more sets.
4. Each set has a weight, and one or more repetitions.

I'm considering a json file, where:

1. Each date attribute has a list of exercise objects.
2. Each exercise object has a name, and a list of set objects.
3. Each set object has a weight attribute and a repetitions attribute.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it with Android, use clases to represent the different entities you have mentioned.

To persist the information inside the phone, I sugest you use the built in sqlite database.

If you plan to build the app as the front end for a rest api or webservice, then yes you can use a json file to exchange informtion with the server. Now, on the server, you would persist the data in a database of your choice. I would go with a relational database like mysql, but for the model you are proposing it would be feasable to also go with a Nosql alternative.